# How to show other_tags columns separately?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have many columns in an attribute of a file downloaded from OSM. But QGIS only shows three columns including one named "other_tags" that includes all my other columns and their value. How do I show all those columns separately?

Answer (score 4):

Since QGIS 3.6, you can use `Explode HStore field` algorithm in Processing Toolbox. This algorithm will explode your HStore field into many fields. There is also support for HStore expression in QGIS since QGIS 3.4.

Before QGIS 3.6, you can open your file with the QuickOSM plugin. This plugin will split your attribute table in the "other_tags".

If it fail, you can still use the QuickOSM plugin, but by giving a custom OSM Conf file following the OGR syntax: http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html

I can detail the answer if needed.